# Rails - how to expose attr_accessor when collecting all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, gon

I am using the `gon` gem to get access to model objects in the front end. So in my controller I have something like this:

`gon.items = @items`

This isn't really a `gon` issue, basically `gon.items` is just an array of all `@items` where each array object `n` has all the attributes of the item `n`, just as if we were to do `@items[n].inspect`

I realized that I want to build a new attribute that's a helper for the front end, so I add this attribute, let's just say `helper_attr` as an `attr_accessor` on `Class Item`. Now in the controller, I am building it like so:

```
gon.items = @items
gon.items.each do |item|
  item.helper_attr = ...... 
end

puts gon.items.map { |i| i.helper_attr }
```

I notice that in the controller, the `puts` is correctly showing that `helper_attr` has indeed been built correctly and is available. However in the front end `gon.items` doesn't have the attribute `helper_attr`.

Is there a way to get it to show, without having to do clunky manual building?

```
# manual building example, instead of gon.items = @items, would do something like
gon.items = []
@items.each do |item|
  built_item = {}
  Item.attribute_names.each do |attr_n|
    built_item[attr_n] = item.send(attr_n)
  end
  built_item["#{helper_attr}"] = .....
  gon.items << built_item
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ActiveModel::Attributes` instead of `attr_accessor`? `attr_accessor` just creates a setter an getter method but it doesn't actually keep track of the "attributes" like `ActiveModel::Attributes`  does for serialization.

Comment: @max thanks, how would I use it in this case? Can you submit an answer>?